# PHP SoapClient, how connect with certificate?

Tags: php, ssl, soap

i create new SoapClient

```
$this->soap = new \SoapClient($this->wdls // WDLS with corect host
, [
    'exceptions' => 0,
    'trace' => TRUE,
    'local_cert' => $this->local_cert, // PEM file
    'passphrase' => $this->passphrase, // password for PEM
    'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
    'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    ]);
$this->soap->getInfo([...]);
```

but I get an error: **Could not connect to host**

I tested the connection using Firefox, and I was able to connect. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to start - was closed port on the server. so I could not reach the remote server.
after all there was a problem with TLS 1.2, the built-in SOAP client did not accept the configuration, it helped me to specify the protocol version manually.

```
$this->soap = new \SoapClient($this->wdls, [
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'trace' => TRUE,
    'local_cert' => $this->local_cert,
    'passphrase' => $this->passphrase,
    //'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2, // not work!
    'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
    "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_2,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT, // it's work!
        ]
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass local_cert as PEM stream and not as local file path?